# How to properly import a txt file into a rich text box in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to import a text file into a rich text box for my Visual Basic project (*Its a Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)*). I copied the text information from the internet, and pasted it into notepad. Then I saved this in a folder I created called txtFiles inside the Bin folder of my project. However, when I used the FileOpen command, it gives me an error.

The code I used:

```
Dim strTemp As String = ""
    rtbReference.Text = Nothing

    FileOpen(1, "../txtFiles/Thriller.txt", OpenMode.Input)

    Do Until EOF(1) = True
        Input(1, strTemp)
        rtbReference.Text = strTemp
    Loop

    FileClose(1)
```

Picture:
[The error that I got when running my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypc1P.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much

Comment: Get rid of that VB^ style of file I/O.  Generally speaking, if you want to work with files then you use members of the System.IO namespace, e.g. the `StreamReader` class.  In the specific case of a `RichTextBox` though, it has its own methods for loading and saving files, so you ought to be using them.

Comment: Also, don't provide links to pictures of error messages.  An error message is text.  Post it as text.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am sorry, but I do not know what a StreamReader class is. Perhaps if you could show me some code?

Comment: Sorry about the error message misunderstanding, I'll be sure to post it as text next time.

Comment: [RichTextBox.LoadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile)

Comment: @Sam: When someone says *You should use a StreamReader instead*, you should spend some time in your favorite search engine to research the suggestion instead of saying *Write some code to show me how*.

Comment: *"I do not know what a StreamReader class is"*.  If only there was a place where you could put words in, hit a button and information about those words would be displayed.  Someone should really invent something like that.  *"Perhaps if you could show me some code"*.  Perhaps you could look for some code for yourself.

Comment: *"Get rid of that VB^ style of file I/O"*. Oops!  Should have been "VB6" rather than "VB^".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more easier methods of working with files in the 21st century. I mean the `IO` namespace provides a handful of methods.

Try any of the following. Add this at the top of your code file

```
Imports System.IO
```

**Method 0: `File.ReadAllText`**

Since the file you want to load is a plain tet file, I suggest you use this.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(pathtofile)
```

**Method 1: `Richtextbox.LoadFile()`**

Someone (or something) has already posted the link to an article on this in the comments but i'm pretty sure you've not gone through it. Well here's how to use it

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile(pathtofile)
```

I use this method for only rtf files but it was completely my decision.

**Method 2 To n - 1**

You need to know how to use a search engine as there are many methods out there that can be used such as the `StreamReader` and so on.